# GWT/Web Java offline application example

Tags: java, gwt, frameworks

Could you link me with some examples of application wrote in GWT, or other Java Framework that works offline? I tried to ask google, but unfortunately i couldn't find anything.

For example: 
installation of this app contains installing tomcat/jetty, and when i want to start it, server is started first, then some portable browser with hard coded address.

Comment: I don't know if this is the way to go - shipping a whole Java server to run a web application? Why not use [Gears](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/GearsGettingStarted) or something similar (HTML5 offers a similar solution and is available in some browsers) to ensure the application works offline?

Comment: last discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511405/java-web-app-as-desktop-app-which-frameworks-should-i-choose 
As a mater of HTML5/Gears well Gears is no longer supported as far as i read, and HTML5 is not fully implemented. I need installer for a offline application.

Comment: But if you are willing to ship a whole server to just run a web application, then why not ship a recent version of a browser that supports fully supports what you need from HTML5?

Comment: Ok... Got point. But. 1. my app uses lucene, and it must be written in java. So i'll need some kind of container that or another. 2. i want to have one code for offline and online version. I'm not quite sure how HTML5 will react on IE 6.0 and unfortunately my app needs to work on it.

Comment: Well, *that* information changes this question quite a lot - why didn't you provide it from the start? :/ Please check my answer (Hudson) - it seems what you are looking for (don't know if Winstone is able to run everything you want, but it's a start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) ([source code](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Source%20code) + [building instructions](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+Hudson)) is written in Java and comes with its own Java server (IIRC, it uses Winstone Servlet Container).

Answer (score 0):

What IDE do you use? eclipse? If so, just install GWT for eclipse and check out the Google Examples and Showcases. Sources can be found there, too. There are also tutorials, which explain how to work local.

[Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/examples/)

Comment: Thx i'lll try that. But also i need real life application. Do you know any ?